# Create new Post with default Category belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a Post/Category manyToMany relations and would like to be able to attach a default category named "Uncategorised" to each new post that is created. How can I do that? A BelongsToMany method only works on the Details page, not on Create page.

```
BelongsToMany::make(__('Categories'), 'categories', Category::class),
```

Comment: "A BelongsToMany method only works on the Details page, not on Create page." what do you mean by this, the relationship will always work?

Comment: @MartinHenriksen yes that is correct. I am not sure what you are asking me though?

Answer (score 2):

You can also set default value to your database field so that you can omit passing category and will be taken default to **Uncategorised** like if you are using MySQL you can do it this way by creating migration

```
$table->text('category')->default(0);
```

Comment: This is also a nice way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Because the BelongsToMany not show on mode create in Post Nova model. So we have to make our custom Select, by add this code to your fields:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    if($request->editMode=="create"){
        $categories = \App\Category::get(['id','name']);
        $options = [];
        foreach($categories as $value){
            $options[$value->id] = $value->name;
        }
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Text::make('Title'),
            Text::make('Summary'),
            Textarea::make('Content'),
            Select::make('Categories', 'category_id')
            ->options($options)
            ->displayUsingLabels()
            ->withMeta(['value' => 1]) // 1 = id of Uncategorised in categories table
        ];
    }
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        Text::make('Title'),
        Text::make('Summary'),
        Textarea::make('Content'),
        BelongsToMany::make('Categories','categories')->display('name'),
    ];
}
```

Don’t forget relationship function in both, Post and Category model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_post', 'post_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

And:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class,'category_post', 'category_id', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

Then, custom the function process the data on mode Create of Post resource page, it’s at nova\src\Http\Controllers\ResourceStoreController.php, change function handle to this:

```
    public function handle(CreateResourceRequest $request)
    {
        $resource = $request->resource();

        $resource::authorizeToCreate($request);

        $resource::validateForCreation($request);

        $model = DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $resource) {
            [$model, $callbacks] = $resource::fill(
                $request, $resource::newModel()
            );

            if ($request->viaRelationship()) {
                $request->findParentModelOrFail()
                        ->{$request->viaRelationship}()
                        ->save($model);
            } else {
                $model->save();
                // your code to save to pivot category_post here
                if(isset($request->category_id)&&($resource=='App\Nova\Post')){
                    $category_id = $request->category_id;
                    $post_id = $model->id;
                    \App\Post::find($post_id)->categories()->attach($category_id);
                }
            }

            ActionEvent::forResourceCreate($request->user(), $model)->save();

            collect($callbacks)->each->__invoke();

            return $model;
        });

        return response()->json([
            'id' => $model->getKey(),
            'resource' => $model->attributesToArray(),
            'redirect' => $resource::redirectAfterCreate($request, $request->newResourceWith($model)),
        ], 201);
    }
}
```

All runs well on my computer. A fun question with me! Hope best to you, and ask me if you need!

Comment: Thanks @protoproto, I have not tested your solution, but thanks for helping.

Comment: Yes, think big and do best! : D

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was saving the data on Post Model in boot().

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function (Post $post) {

        $post->categories()->attach([1]);

    });
}
```